# hashbang urls not working

Tags: angularjs, hashbang

I use angular ui route, works fine - but in browsers that doesn't support html5mode, and it has to fall back to hashbang, links aren't working.

**www.test.com/something** < works

**www.test.com/#/something** < not working.  (redirects to test.com)

not quite sure how to make the hashbanged links work ?

my desperate attempt:

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
  // HTML5 history API is available.
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
});
} else {
    // hashbang mode.
    window.location.hash = '/'; 
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
    });
  }

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
  .state('statistics', {
      url: "/statistics/:id",
      templateUrl: '../path/statistics.html',
      controller: 'ResultCtrl'
    }
);
```

Comment: @CallumLinington read https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router docs, and https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location without luck ;I

Comment: But if you read `$location service configuration` under that heading it explicitly tells you how to enable hashbang mode...

Comment: is it a problem with the relative path in the templateurl? do you have a base tag in your html?

Comment: yes i have a base tag in my head. which points to index.html

Comment: shouldn't it point to "/" ? <base href="/"/>

Answer (score 1):

you just need to do this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
}).hashPrefix("#");
```

Comment: usually you would have a "!" in hashprefix to get the classic #! hashbang. having .hashprefix('#') just adds a second hashtag to the url -> www.something.com/##/view1

Comment: yes @AndersPedersen But he was asking for #/something so i believe he wants it to work with #

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled html5mode. This mode basically means the site doesn't route with hashbang urls. I don't think you can support both.

Remove this code:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
});
```

### Update

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#html5-mode

According to the docs you don't need to test for push state support, it automatically falls back to hashbangs if its not supported.

Comment: if html5mode is not available (using older browser) it will automatically go back to hashbang mode from what i could read from docs.

Comment: you updated the post with what i just told you ? :) the reason for the check was a desperate attempt to edit the URL without # if html5mode not supported.

Comment: yeh i was updating it when u commented. if in your code somewhere you call $location.path('/somethingvalid') (in ie9) what path does it try to browse to?